# change URL in from anchor tag using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to change the Url of the below given anchor tag

```
<a href="pubmed/2562222"></a>
```

I want to replace inside url with like

```
<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25562222"></a>
```

I want to replace with preg_replace but i don't know exactly.please help me out of this

Comment: You've really got to improve your question and show some effort. I suspect you've created a new account and asked almost the exact question that has been closed three times on your previous account : http://stackoverflow.com/users/2459458/user2459458

Comment: dude iam not getting how to display the code here

Comment: Edit your question, paste your code. There is even a nice code-formatting utility in the editor toolbar. If you happen to make a mistake while pasting, no problem. We can show you how to fix that. But you've got to include some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
$patterns = '/pubmed\/2562222/';
$replacements = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2562222';
$string = '<a href="pubmed/2562222"></a>';
print( preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string));
```

This will output

```
<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2562222"></a>
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/biROi1)

Comment: > Thanks dude..it's really fine..and please help me how to integrate
> with this script?

    $contentss = file_get_contents("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?LinkName=pubmed_pubmed&from_uid=18032633" );
 

    preg_match('/<div class="rprt">(.*)<\/div>/',$contentss,$matches);
    preg_replace(

> //$result = $matches[0];

    echo "<div class='relatedcitations'>";
    echo "$matches[1]";
    echo "</div>";

Comment: @Raju You are welcome dude. I'm sorry i cannot help you with that since I don't know what you are doing with that or what you plan to do with that. If you feel the answer was correct please accept it, so you will also help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score

Comment: Hi i have done exactly same with your code.. I got this URL Changed but one forward slash coming before the URL please help me..htef="/http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18032633"